# When I use GuzzleHttp on localhost hang up my Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

When I use `GuzzleHttp` and send the request, my laravel program is interrupted and I will stop the server and run it again. if using online API or just use localhost without port number, not problem and work. but when use port 8000 or any port, the Laravel app hangs up.

My code is

```
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 2,
        'client_secret' => 'AXXwkDGiuEewwd1tza4haWrz6Gku0LRGgLIaayxC',
        'username' => 'saeed',
        'password' => '12345678',
    ]
]);
return json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the port explicit as described here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/http-messages.html#port

```
$request->setPort(8000);
```